# Which json style is best for Android + iOS apps

Tags: android, ios, json, web-services

I am developing an app for iOS and Android in both apps I am going to use web services. I got two types of services from my developer. One Return WCF data and other return HTTP header.

1- WCF Style

```
{"d":[
{"Key":"Data Key 1", "Value":"Value 1"},
{"Key":"Data Key 2", "Value":"Value 2"},
{"Key":"Data Key 3", "Value":"Value 3"},
{"Key":"Data Key 4", "Value":"Value 4"},
{"Key":"Data Key 5", "Value":"Value 5"}]}
```

2- Http Header Style:

```
{"Data Key 1":"Value 1","Data Key2 ":"Value 2","Data Key2 ":"Value 2","Data Key3 ":"Value 3","Data Key4":"Value 4"}
```

My Question is that which one i have to use for my apps???? and Which one is Standard jSon format??

I already have consume no. 2 types of services in my Android App.

Comment: Its depends on your output data !

Comment: @NiravRanpara Above are the two types of data I am getting from services. Which one is better for me to use???

Comment: @NiravRanpara Thanks. But can you give some reason why Http Header. I Used HTTP Header type data already which works fine for my android apps. But i don't know about ios. Will this work in iOS t0o???
before making any decision I want to conform that HTTP header will work on both with there built-in Json Parsers.

Answer (score 1):

In our app, Android or iOS, we check the JSON format [on the link](http://jsonlint.com/).

So, I think both of your sample are valid and correct.

In the real project, we use `WCF Style` JSON, for we think it has a better organization.

Comment: Is there any diffrence in Parser of both styles?? or both styles can be parsed with same parser???

Comment: Thanks. :) I have desided to use Header format. Because I already used this in my Android App and android JSONParser working fine on this. As well data returned in this format is less (Some Bytes) that WCF style.